# 'Localized' services when leaving Germany?

Tags: germany, services

Are there any regulations that protect the consumer in case of leaving Germany, when the services that he have purchased can't be served outside Germany?

For example, if an emigrant has an Internet and cable TV contract for 2 years and leaves Germany in the middle of that contract, does he have to pay for them for 1 year, or the provider is obliged to accept the termination of the contract without extra fees, because he'll be unable to provide the services outside Germany?

I don't ask if some providers are offering such possibility, but if there's a law requiring them to do so.

Comment: Are there even such rules if, for example, you move from one bit of Germany to another bit where your cable TV provider doesn't offer service? (I suspect not?)

Comment: @Gagravarr There is, in fact!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a law about that, namely paragraph 46 of the telecommunication law (in German: § 46 TKG).

Technically, there is nothing special about moving abroad, what the law says is that your telecommunication providers have to offer the same service at your new address when you move or, if they can't (which would generally be the case if you move abroad…) allow you to terminate the contract with a 3-month notice.

There are also countless forum posts by people having a lot of trouble getting large telcos to apply this particular provision of the law.